# Change content of div in keyframes animation CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have following code.

```css
#mf-loader-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
}
.mf-loader-circle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #03C9A9;
  top: -15px;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #03C9A9;
}
.mf-loader-text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  top: 20px;
}
#one-text {
  left: -10px;
  -webkit-animation: cl 3s;
}
#two-text {
  left: 200px;
  -webkit-animation: cl 3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
}
#three-text {
  left: 480px;
  -webkit-animation: cl 3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
}
@-webkit-keyframes cl {
  from {
    color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
  }
  to {
    color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 1);
  }
}
#two {
  left: 240px;
}
#three {
  left: 490px;
}
#mf-loader {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #03C9A9;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 5s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: mymove 5s;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mf-loader-container">

  <div id="mf-loader">
    <div class="mf-loader-circle" id="one">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="mf-loader-circle" id="two">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="mf-loader-circle" id="three">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="mf-loader-text" id="one-text">
      Each day will be better than last.
      <br>This one especially
    </div>
    <div class="mf-loader-text" id="two-text">
      Subscribing .. Thank you for subscribing. We appreciate it!
    </div>
    <div class="mf-loader-text" id="three-text">
      DONE
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is an animated checkout-like action which is done with CSS alone. I'm trying to change the content of the circle once the text appears to check mark `&#10003;` - is there any way to change the content using content tag in css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the content (the 1, 2, 3 numbers) to `:after` pseudo-elements and set the content there. Then, apply that to each of the circles. With this, you can include them into your animation by changing `content:"";`
Change "check" to whatever you need.

```css
.mf-loader-circle:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#one:after {
  content: "1";
  -webkit-animation: check1 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
#two:after {
  content: "2";
  -webkit-animation: check2 3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
#three:after {
  content: "3";
  -webkit-animation: check3 3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes check1 {
  from {
    content: "1";
  }
  to {
    content: "check";
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes check2 {
  from {
    content: "2";
  }
  to {
    content: "check";
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes check3 {
  from {
    content: "3";
  }
  to {
    content: "check";
  }
}
#mf-loader-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
}
.mf-loader-circle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #03C9A9;
  top: -15px;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #03C9A9;
}
.mf-loader-text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  top: 20px;
}
#one-text {
  left: -10px;
  -webkit-animation: cl 3s;
}
#two-text {
  left: 200px;
  -webkit-animation: cl 3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
}
#three-text {
  left: 480px;
  -webkit-animation: cl 3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
}
@-webkit-keyframes cl {
  from {
    color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
  }
  to {
    color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 1);
  }
}
#two {
  left: 240px;
}
#three {
  left: 490px;
}
#mf-loader {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #03C9A9;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 5s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: mymove 5s;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mf-loader-container">

  <div id="mf-loader">
    <div class="mf-loader-circle" id="one">
    </div>
    <div class="mf-loader-circle" id="two">
    </div>
    <div class="mf-loader-circle" id="three">
    </div>
    <div class="mf-loader-text" id="one-text">
      Each day will be better than last.
      <br>This one especially
    </div>
    <div class="mf-loader-text" id="two-text">
      Subscribing .. Thank you for subscribing. We appreciate it!
    </div>
    <div class="mf-loader-text" id="three-text">
      DONE
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Here's a summary of the changes:

---

- Removed the content from your circles in the HTML.

---

- Created an `:after` pseudo-element, common to all your circles.

---

```
.mf-loader-circle:after {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Here, I used 2D transforms to position the number in the center with `position:absolute;`

- Set each of the `content:"";` attributes to the necessary numbers using the elements' IDs.
- Created an animation for the different numbers, for example:

---

```
#one:after {
  content:"1";
  -webkit-animation: check1 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes check1{
  from {
    content:"1";
  }
  to {
    content:"check";
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** add the corresponding vendor prefixes.

Comment: How can the content inside :after be changed inside keyframes ?

Comment: I couldn't add your particular checkmark though, maybe that's because of the font.

Comment: If Unicode is used instead of hex , that will work too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:before` to assign each number using `content: 'number';`. Then, you can animate the check transition smoothly in a keyframe by changing the color to white at `50%`, then assigning it the checkmark value.

For this solution you only need to define 1 keyframe animation.

**CSS Changes**

- Using `content` to display your numbers instead of inside of the html.
- Setting up the keyframe animation, delay (except for the first one), and fill-mode.

  ```
  .mf-loader-circle#two:before {
    content: '2';
    animation: changeLetter 2s;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }
  ```
- Changing the color to white, then assigning it the checkmark.

  ```
  @keyframes changeLetter {
    50% {
      color: white;
    }
    100% {
      content: "\2713";
    }
  }
  ```

```css
#mf-loader-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
}
.mf-loader-circle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #03C9A9;
  top: -15px;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #03C9A9;
}

.mf-loader-circle#one:before {
  content: '1';
  -webkit-animation: changeLetter 2s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: changeLetter 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.mf-loader-circle#two:before {
  content: '2';
  -webkit-animation: changeLetter 2s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: changeLetter 2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.mf-loader-circle#three:before {
  content: '3';
  -webkit-animation: changeLetter 2s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: changeLetter 2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.mf-loader-text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  top: 20px;
}
#one-text {
  left: -10px;
  -webkit-animation: cl 3s;
}
#two-text {
  left: 200px;
  -webkit-animation: cl 3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
}
#three-text {
  left: 480px;
  -webkit-animation: cl 3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
}
@-webkit-keyframes cl {
  from {
    color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
  }
  to {
    color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 1);
  }
}
#two {
  left: 240px;
}
#three {
  left: 490px;
}
#mf-loader {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #03C9A9;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 5s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: mymove 5s;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-@keyframes changeLetter {
  50% {
    color: white;
  }
  100% {
    content: "\2713";
  }
}

@keyframes changeLetter {
  50% {
    color: white;
  }
  100% {
    content: "\2713";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mf-loader-container">

  <div id="mf-loader">
    <div class="mf-loader-circle" id="one">
    </div>
    <div class="mf-loader-circle" id="two">
    </div>
    <div class="mf-loader-circle" id="three">
    </div>
    <div class="mf-loader-text" id="one-text">
      Each day will be better than last.
      <br>This one especially
    </div>
    <div class="mf-loader-text" id="two-text">
      Subscribing .. Thank you for subscribing. We appreciate it!
    </div>
    <div class="mf-loader-text" id="three-text">
      DONE
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdpg6tcj/2/)**